# 401 error at calling APIs in Web App in Azure sending token, without AAD

Tags: asp.net, azure, jwt, identity, http-status-code-401

I have an application built in .Net 6 and React (same solution), I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer Version="6.0.16" and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.16" to manage user authentication. The app is hosted on Azure Web App, it was working fine until a few days ago, when it started throwing 401 errors. The authentication API returns a valid token and then sends it and includes it in the request header to the other APIs, however these keep returning 401. Using Postman throws 401 too. Locally it doesn't happen.

I'm not using AAD so I understand is not necessary configure scopes? I'm not sure about that. My Azure Web App doesn't have any Authorization configuration, but was working well until days ago. Thanks for the help!

This is my configuration from server side and code

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  },
  "JWTSettings": {
    "Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Issuer": "CoreIdentity",
    "Audience": "CoreIdentityUser",
    "DurationInMinutes": 30
  },
  "PageSizeGrids": 20,
  "CultureSettings": {
    "CultureName": "en-US",
    "NumberDecimalSeparator": ".",
    "NumberGroupSeparator": ","
  },
  "EPPlus": {
    "ExcelPackage": {
      "LicenseContext": "NonCommercial"
    }
  },
  "EmailSettings": {
    "EmailHost": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "EmailPassword": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
  },
  "StorageAccount": {
    "Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "StorageAccountName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },


}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInfrastructure();
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
    options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>()).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });

builder.Services.AddPersistenceInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSharedInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticatedUserService, AuthenticatedUserService>();


builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt => //horas que dura el link de reseteo de password
   opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("myCorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            {
                //builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()

                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin =>
                {
                    if (origin.StartsWith("https://example.com")) return true;
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
});



var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{

    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
     new CultureInfo("es-AR"),
 new CultureInfo("en-US"),
 new CultureInfo("es"),
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("es-AR"),
    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    // UI strings that we have localized.
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});


app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("myCorsPolicy");
app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireCors("myCorsPolicy");


app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    try
    {
        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

        await DefaultRoles.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
        await DefaultSuperAdmin.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log.Warning(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB");
    }
    finally
    {
        //Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

app.Run();
```

```
public static void AddPersistenceInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            string? dbConnectionString;
            string? jWTSettingsKey;
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
            {
                dbConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection");
                jWTSettingsKey = configuration["JWTSettings:Key"];
            }
            else
            {
                dbConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_DbConnectionAzure");
                jWTSettingsKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_JWT_KEY");
            }


            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString,
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName))
            ,ServiceLifetime.Transient);
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            })
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            #region Services
            services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            services.AddTransient<IFileService, FileService>();
            #endregion

            services.Configure<JWTSettings>(configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings"));

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
      .AddJwtBearer(o =>
      {
          o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
          o.SaveToken = false;
          o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
              ValidateIssuer = true,
              ValidateAudience = true,
              ValidateLifetime = true,
              ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
              ValidIssuer = configuration["JWTSettings:Issuer"],
              ValidAudience = configuration["JWTSettings:Audience"],
              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jWTSettingsKey))
          };
      });
            

            #endregion

        }
```

I already tried changing the cors configuration, allowing all origins. I also configured the CORS in Azure (Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)
I also tried to configure API manager in Azure but I am not sure if it is necessary and it has a cost that I have to consult with the client.